# How can I retrieve the N most popular tweets for a country using the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

**TL;DR**: I want to be able to retrieve the N most popular tweets for any arbitrary country within the last X hours (up to 24 hours)

**More detail**

I want to show the details of the most popular tweets by geographic region (country) over the past few hours (adjustable up to 24 hours). How can I use the Twitter REST API to achieve this (v1.1 or v2)?

There are endpoints for querying tweets and filtering by popularity, but they require a search string (e.g. "NASA") and return the most popular tweets matching that search string. I am not interested in the contents of the tweets, I just want to know what is most popular.

I plan on using this functionality to show a world map (using Leaflet) to summarise the most popular tweets by country for the past day.

I am using `Twit` in `NodeJS` but not looking for answers specific to Node, rather how to leverage the capabilities of the API.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way that this can be done directly through the API itself (V1 or V2). I also do not think that this is going to be a trivial task at all.

What I would suggest is using the search endpoint...

> - V1: [Reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets)
> - V2: [Reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference) Note that to use geolocation search parameters (see below) you'll need academic access.

... in conjunction with one of the geolocation search parameters. For example, you could pull some subset of tweets from within a country (you will not be able to download all tweets within a single country on any given day, not to mention all countries). After you get this data, you'll need to do some of your own data processing based on how you want to define "popular" (e.g. retweets, likes, etc.) and then go from there.

As I said earlier, this seems like a very large project and not something that can be solved simply with the Twitter API.